# MYSQL Step through one table and update another

Tags: mysql

Following a forum update I have been left with blank fields that should have been filled.
I'm trying to update a table named thread with with fields from a table named post. I need to process the post table ordered by threadid, postid.

```
Table: post
Field: postid - data is valid
Field: threadid - data is valid

Table: thread
Field: threadid - data is valid and matches post.threadid
Field: firstpostid - should be first post.postid found
Field: lastpostid - should be last post.postid found
Field: lastpost - should be last post.postid found
```

Everything I try is yielding the same value for firstpostid and lastpostid

This is about as close as I got trying establish a method to update one field at a time. I can't set the order correctly.

```
UPDATE thread
INNER JOIN post ON post.threadid = thread.threadid
SET thread.firstpostid = 
IF(thread.firstpostid > post.postid, post.postid, thread.firstpostid)
WHERE postid <> 0
```

Any pointers would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use correlated subqueries, though this is likely the most inefficient approach. For reasonable performance, we definitely want to have an appropriate index available, for example:

```
 ... ON post (thread_id, post_id)
```

(any index with `thread_id` and `post_id` as the leading columns, in that order)

We can use a scalar subquery to retrieve the `post_id` value to be assigned to each column. (In this context, the subqueries must be scalar: the query must return at most one row containing a single value:

```
 UPDATE thread t
    SET t.firstpostid = 
        ( SELECT p1.post_id
            FROM post p1
           WHERE p1.thread_id = t.thread_id
          ORDER BY p1.thread_id, p1.post_id
          LIMIT 0,1
        )
      , t.secondpostid = 
        ( SELECT p2.post_id
            FROM post p2
           WHERE p2.thread_id = t.thread_id
          ORDER BY p2.thread_id, p2.post_id 
          LIMIT 1,1
        )
      , t.lastpostid = 
        ( SELECT p9.post_id
            FROM post p9
           WHERE p9.thread_id = t.thread_id
          ORDER BY p9.thread_id DESC, p9.post_id DESC
          LIMIT 0,1
        )
```

The "trick" is the LIMIT clause which is applied after the ORDER BY.

`LIMIT 0,1` says skip 0 rows and return the next 1 rows
`LIMIT 1,1` says skip 1 rows and return the next 1 rows

To get the last post_id, we reverse the order of the sort (`DESC` = descending, vs. the default `ASC` = ascending).

Comment: I appreciate your help but I'm still struggling. The tables concerned are small 5300 post and 333 threads so I don't mind using simple inefficient code to get the job. I would be very happy to step through the tables a couple of times to set one field per pass. I think I could manage that if I knew where to use an index or on order by instruction.

Comment: Ideally I need to step through the post table a record at a time using the order threadid, postid and write to the table thread. Is that possible?

Comment: It would be possible to process rows individually RBAR (row by agonizing row). That's an approach that a lot of neophytes take. That approach is less than ideal, because it turns out to be excruciatingly slow and prohibitively resource intensive on large sets. Which inevitably leads to the "why is this so slow on my production volume, when it worked on my small test set". It is more efficient to operate on "sets" of data.

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice. I think I can mark this problem solved.